# Validating a field with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to validate a form field so that the post won't proceed if the field is set with a value. So my field is:

```
 <input type="text" name="validator" id="validator" value="" title="validator" class="myClass" />
```

and then I'm using the following snippet to check if it has been filled:

```
 jQuery("form").submit(function(){
     <?php if(isset($_POST['validator']) || !empty($_POST['validator'])){
                        die("Unable to write to database");
                        }

                ?>
      });
```

but when I hit the submit button the form continues and registers the new user.  What't wrong with my code please ?

Comment: you can't use php in a jquery even like submit, because the php code is server-side and the javascript is client side

Comment: You can't weave PHP and JavaScript like that. Use AJAX.

Comment: PHP code cannot run in jQuery submit event.

Comment: You should try to use a C# function within your javascript, and run it within PHP...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this php function to check if a filed is empty upon clicking submit if it if erro will pop out if not do whatever

```
if (empty($_POST["validator"])) {
            $validatorErr = "Name is required";
} else {
...
}
}
```

Then add a button and the error variable u have created above to your html

```
<input type="text" name="validator" id="validator" value="" title="validator" class="myClass" />
<span class="error">* <br><?php echo $ironingErr;?></span>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```